# How to create a class based column-wise view in razor/mvc 4

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to create a view generically based on my class in a column-wise table layout.

the model is:

```
public class Client
{
    [DisplayName("Client Account")]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Client Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Home Phone")]
    public string PhoneH { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Emergency Phone")]
    public string PhoneE { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Alternate Phone")]
    public string PhoneA { get; set; }
    public string Directions { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Comments")]
    public string SComment { get; set; }
}
```

in the form of

Field 1    value1

Field 2    value2

Field 3    value3

Is there a way to do it so that the first column uses one style and the second column uses another style?

i am trying to do this generically based on the properties of the class.

I am using MVC4/razor/VS2012

Many thanks!

Comment: This can help you:[quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have the correct terminology basically I need help making a "display template". Now I have something to google on. :)

Comment: Search here on SO. There are hundreds of questions about this topic here.

Comment: I searched, I must be using the wrong key words. Do you have an example?

Comment: Something like this may sufice: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+editor+template or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+display+template

Comment: You will have to search through the questions, but the first ones for editor templates will get you started. Display templates are just like editor templates, but you have to render the desired values instead of the inputs.